# Java Compare a String to a integer in Java

Tags: java

I have this method which is supposed to compare a String to an integer in java

My string used to be a Long integer then i changed it to a string- It is supposed to iterate through the String number by number and compare it to the index of the loop

Here's my code

```
private StringBuilder convert(long wordSum) {

    String tempLongString = new String();
    numberString2 = null;

    tempLongString = String.valueOf(wordSum);



    for(int i = 0; i < tempLongString.length(); i++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            if(x == tempLongString.charAt(i)) {             
                numberString2.append(letters[x]);
                System.out.println(numberString2);
            }
        }
    }


    return numberString2;
}
```

I know there's alot of code in here that i don't talk about but right now im curious as to why its not running the loop- The if statement should work

For people asking: The Long number is `2343638086` which is not in the string `tempLongString`

Comment: Have you tried to check what `#charAt` returns? If not: do it now.

Comment: @Tom - charAt is returning the correct values.

Comment: So you don't know what `#charAt` returns. Please do what I said: look up what it does: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-

Comment: @Tom - When i do tempLongString.charAt(i) it is returning exactly what i want i too.

Comment: It returns the `char` in this position, not the numerical value of this char. Since that `char` is obviously not in range of 0 to 10 (it is in range of 48 to 57) it will always be `false`.

Comment: @Tom - That could be it.

Comment: Btw: your whole method code can be replaces by `new StringBuilder().append(Math.abs(wordSum));`. You're already getting a long, so you don't need to check if it contains numbers ... yes, a long can only contain numbers. The only char you "erase" is the minus sign, `Math.abs` can do this as well.

Comment: @Tom - No, With my other methods i have to do other thing's to this string of numbers- i need to find another way to compre them, the integer x to each individual integer inside the string- any ideas?

Comment: You're not comparing them (not like in a real "compare" method, I mean), you try to convert your `long` to a `StringBuilder`. At least in this code, which might be different from your real one.

Comment: I can't answer since it's been marked as a duplicate, but this comparison worked in my testing:  `if (x + '0' == tempLongString.charAt(i)) {`  Once it starts working, there's an error because `numberString2` is `null` instead of a `StringBuilder` instance so set it initially to `new StringBuilder()`

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure it's not running the loop? Try putting something else in that print statement just to see if it's doing nothing. I can't fully test your code because I don't know what numberString2 is or what the letters[] is.

if numberString2 is a StringBuilder you can declare it as a new StringBuilder instead of null maybe?

Comment: I added something else in the println- it's not accessing the IF statement for some reason

Comment: maybe because x never == a char in tempLongString, try adding a print statement showing what tempLongString is after you've made it and see what it actually is.

Comment: Not "maybe", of course it won't pass this comparison. His chars won't have the checked range.